How to properly align a scope and a node?
I am using two different approaches to draw similar looking blocks. Using first approach, I draw first block (top row) made of rectangular nodes inside a scope and name it as group 1. Similarly, second block is drawn with nodes inside a scope and named as group 2. This, however, is too verbose, as each node has to be described elaborately and named individually. Since any single node inside the (scope) block is of little interest to me (except when manipulating node display with append after command), later I opt for (second approach) blocks to be drawn as node (group 3). Such nodes, apparently, are drawn with a custom tikzpicture with required options to make them look like regular nodes (the ones drawn previously inside scope).
The problem is, however, group 2 and group 3 are not aligning properly to the left. I tried relatively positioning the node right below of the leftmost node of group 2 and anchoring the tikzpicture containing (group 3) node to west, but to no avail.
Please also suggest what other alternatives are to drawing similar blocks. I know chains library allows drawing nodes at certain orientations, but I don't know if it flexible enough to allow modifying (like crossing out) certain nodes afterwards ?
I attach my MWE code herewith for reference.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc,fit,arrows.meta,calc,chains,patterns,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Define a simple command to create adjacent rectangles
\newcommand{\adjacentrectangles}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \foreach \col/\txt [count=\i] in {#1} {
            \node[
                rectangle,
                draw,
                minimum width=0.15cm,
                minimum height=1.2cm,
                fill=\col,
                anchor=west,
                inner sep=2pt,
                outer sep=1pt,
                font=\small
            ] at (\i*0.45cm,0) {\txt};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  inner sep=2mm,
    CVrect/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=blue!40,minimum width=0.15cm,minimum height=1.2cm,font=\small,              inner sep=2pt,outer sep=1pt},
    CVrect crossed out/.style={
        CVrect, 
        append after command={node [fit=(\tikzlastnode),draw=red!50!black!50,thick,inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,cross out]{}}
        },
    ltextbox/.style={rectangle,draw=none,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1.0cm,inner sep=1pt,font=\small}, % text to write on left
    CVarrow/.style={->,>={stealth},shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt,line width=0.1cm,color=gray!80},
    start chain=1,
    start chain=2,
    start chain=3
  ]

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=group 1]
\node (A1) [CVrect] {A};
\node (B1) [CVrect,fill=red!30,right=0.01cm of A1] {B};
\node (C1) [CVrect,fill=purple!20,right=0.01cm of B1] {C};
\node (D1) [CVrect crossed out, fill=blue!60,right=0.01cm of C1] {D};
\end{scope}

\node[ltextbox, left=0.25cm of group 1,text width=4cm,font=\footnotesize] {Lines tested individually} ;

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=group 2]
\node (A2) [CVrect,below=1.2cm of A1] {A};
\node (B2) [CVrect,fill=red!30,right=0.01cm of A2] {B};
\node (C2) [CVrect,fill=purple!20,right=0.01cm of B2] {C};

\node (I2) [CVrect crossed out,fill=pink!12,right=0.4cm of C2] {I};
\node (J2) [CVrect,fill=pink!12,right=0.01cm of I2] {J};
\node (K2) [CVrect,fill=pink!12,right=0.01cm of J2] {K};
\end{scope}

\node[ltextbox, left=0.25cm of group 2,text width=4cm,font=\footnotesize] {Continue to test lines plus new lines (I,J and K).\\ Some lines (known to be a susceptible, i.e.,``F'',\\ from previous testing) may be discarded.} ;

\coordinate (mid1) at ($(B1.south)!0.5!(C1.south)$);
% \coordinate (mid2) at ($(C2.north)!0.5!(I2.north)$);
% 
% \draw[CVarrow] (mid1.south) -- (mid2.north);

\draw[CVarrow] (mid1) -- (mid1|-group 2.north);

\node[below=1cm of A2,anchor=west] (group 3) {\adjacentrectangles{blue!40/A,red!30/B,purple!20/C,blue!60/D,green!20/E, gray!26/G,pink!12/H,yellow!45/J,pink!12/K}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Welcome! Nesting tikzpictures isn't supported. Sometimes it works, but it is not expected to. If you really know what you're doing and can compensate for the side-effects you don't want, you can nest in a limited range of cases. But if you know enough to do that, you will also avoid doing it in 99.9999% of cases. Why not use a matrix of nodes instead? Otherwise, you could save the nodes into a box and then use the box inside the picture. That is safe.

I'm really thankful that you brought up the logic of nesting to not work as expected. I didn't know about that.

There are questions about it somewhere ... about why not and what you need to do if you have to and ... why not again. Almost always, it is easier not ;).

Nesting tikzpictures isn't supported and isn't expected to work. Instead, I suggest using a matrix of nodes. For example,
\documentclass{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/723023/
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
  nodes={minimum height=15mm, draw, fill=red!5,text width=1em,align=center},
  column sep=2.5pt,
  row sep=50pt,
  column 1/.style={nodes={fill=blue!50}},
  column 2/.style={nodes={fill=red!25}},
  column 3/.style={nodes={fill=red!35}},
  column 4/.style={nodes={fill=blue!65}},
  column 5/.style={nodes={fill=green!25}},
  column 6/.style={nodes={fill=gray!35}},
  column 8/.style={nodes={fill=yellow}},
  ]
  {
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & &|[fill=red!5]| I & J & K \\
    A & B & C & D & E & G & H & J & K \\
  };
  \foreach \i/\j in {m-1-4/red!50,m-2-5/red!35} {
    \draw [\j] (\i.south east) -- (\i.north west) (\i.north east) -- (\i.south west);
  }
  \draw [gray,line width=3pt,-Stealth,shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt] ($(m-1-2.south)!.5!(m-1-3.south)$) coordinate (a) -- (a |- m-2-1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Wow! The for loop for crossing out...code looks much better and customizable.
